# Chargin energy and released it while mouse button is held down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to accumulate a certain amount of energy and release it when the mouse button is Released. Right now when the energy level reaches the maximum, the energy level is set to 0 and the function just restarts accumulating from the beginning creating a loop.

```
IEnumerator AttackCharge()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1) && energyLevel < energyMax)
        {
            energyLevel += 1;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(playRate);
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            if (energyLevel == energyMax)
            {
                FxPlayerAttack.Stop();
                FxPlayerAttack.Play();
                shootSound.PlayOneShot(attackSound);

                GetComponentInChildren<ParticleCollision>().attackValue = energyLevel;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

                energyLevel = 0;
                GetComponentInChildren<ParticleCollision>().attackValue = energyLevel;
            }

            if (energyLevel < energyMax)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
                energyLevel = 0;
            }
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

I need to accumulate the energy while the button is held down. When the button is Up the energy should be released with the max value reached during the charging phase, the energy level should return to 0 and the accumulation should stop until the button is pressed again.

Comment: what's `playRate`?

Comment: `playRate` it's a float to determine the delta time to execute sounds, particle systems etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`GetMouseButtonUp` only returns true on the *single frame* that the button was released. Your code `yields` then.**

Lets walk through it:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(1) ...
```

The user has let go of their mouse as they wish to attack, so this is false.

```
else {
    yield return null;
}
```

So you yield and wait for the next frame. Then when execution resumes:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
```

This is false because the user released the mouse button *last* frame. You should nest this entire block inside the else-statement *above* the `yield return null` line.

Comment: Even then the `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1)` case might not be catched if it happens in a frame during `yield return new WaitForSeconds(playRate);`. And you can't simply nest the lines wrapped by it into the `else` block because the `else` block is also executed if `energyLevel >= energyMax` ...

Comment: it's working, thanks. the only thing is I need to store the accumulated energy and on mouse up release only that value. how can I do that without having to use `tempEnergy?

Comment: @derHugo The secondary condition doesn't really affect things, because the stuff you'd be adding to the `else` would/should still include the check for `GetMouseButtonUp`: if they're above max energy the attack still won't fire until that release happens.

Comment: @bibrosko You can use a variable within the function scope. It looks like you have `tempEnergy` declared at the class level: you don't need to do that. Coroutines maintain local scope even through a `yield`.

Comment: @Draco18s I understand but my problem now is that the energy level (and/or energyTemp) doesn't reset when I release the button. what I need is to store the energy level, put this value in the attack value of the children object, than reset all the energy levels. if I accumulate energyMax this value should be used, but if I accumulate only 1 the value of 1 should be used instead

Comment: @bibrosko I think this is because your statements are out of order. It should be `<ParticleCollision>().attackValue  = energyLevel` first, only after you do that should you set `energyLevel` back to zero.

Comment: @Draco. yes you were right. Anw, I made some change and I updated the code in the answer. My `energyLevel` doesn't reset when `energyLevel < energyMax`

Comment: @bibrosko You shouldn't edit your question with your fixed code, it makes it so that future readers can't understand what your problem is and why the answers address it.

Comment: oh, I see. I tried to paste the new code in a comment but it was too long. the system suggested me to edit my answer instead. how can I correctly add updated code?